# How to append variable to end of url?

Tags: php, url, get

wondering how it is possible to have an `anchor` which adds a variable to the end of an `URL`?

So something like `/?filter=1` would turn into `/?filter=1&p=1`

Cheers

EDIT:

If anyone's interested, I found my own solution in the following format, it's dynamic and requires no editing! :)

```
//CREATE LINKS BASED ON CURRENT VARIABLES
//REMOVE PARAMETERS WHICH WON'T APPEAR TWICE
    $v = array("p");
    foreach($v as $i) {unset($_GET[$i]);}
    $uri = http_build_query($_GET);
    #if there is a current variable, add & to link
    $uri .= count($_GET)>0 ? "&" : NULL;
```

and your links would be formatted as such:

```
echo "<a href='?".$uri."p=$x'>$x</a>";
```

Comment: an anchor? what do you mean? when you click something you can easliy do that. or are u talking about a function do get the current url of a page, and then add a parameter to it

Comment: try to find it on google before you ask. [w3school] [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp] and [php.net] [http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php]

Comment: Yes RPM I meant to add parameter, sorry if it wasn't clear enough - got a lot of stuff on! Josua try reading my question again! I know how to add a variable onto an URL, but I'm clearly asking how to add one on if I already have one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep adding parameters to the end of your URLS as you suggest:

```
www.example.com/?one=1&two=2&three=3
```

These will then be available as `$_GET["one"]`, `$_GET["two"]` and `$_GET["three"]` respectively.

Comment: Haha I think I ended up looking for a much more complicated solution than I needed!

Comment: Please select this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Found a slightly better solution (imo), still a useful workaround if it's a simple query however not too great when certain ones aren't set. Would need to have a few operators in to set ampersands etc.